# How to connect mysql and weka?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, weka

I have added dependency of both weka and mysql jdbc driver with maven. Now, in the src/main/resources folder, I placed the DatabaseUtil.properties file:

```
jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances
```

But, when I try to connect with weka..

```
query = new InstanceQuery();

query.setUsername("infinite");
uery.setPassword("skills");
query.setQuery("select * from normalizeddata");

Instances train = query.retrieveInstances();
//
```

Then, I am getting the following errors:

```
trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:idb=experiments.prp
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is `jdbc.idbDriver`? Your property file declares `jdbcDriver`.

Comment: According to a Pentaho WEKA architect, these are just warnings. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?82144-quot-Trying-to-add-database-driver-quot-issue&p=256989#post256989 If it is not working, I think it's something else.